# не применяются стили django,

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, django

Есть не большой проект в котором мне нужно постоянно обновлять css, это будет ТВ на котором присутствует таблица с светами, в зависимости от класса должен изменить цвет. Сам ТВ почему-то отказывается сам это делать, нагуглил решение, применять каждое обновление страницы новую версию css, но не знаю что написать в urls.py что бы работало.

подключение css:

```
    <script src="{% static 'main_table/site.css' %}?version={% now "U" %}"></script>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/main_table/favicon.ico')),
url(r'\/static\/main_table\/site\.css\?version=[\s\S]*', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/main_table/favicon.ico')),
path('', views.main),
```

]

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="{% static 'main_table/site.css' %}?version={% now "U" %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

я вместо link использовал

```
<script src="{% static 'main_table/site.css' %}?version={% now "U" %}"></script>
```

случайно скопировал.